# Метафора "Сердце тянет руки"

Tags: стилистика

В одном из своих интервью известный музыкальный критик Сергей Соседов назвал строку из песни Пугачевой "Сердце тянет руки" графоманством. Как можно ее охарактеризовать с точки зрения стилистики?

Comment: Серж, обратите внимание, что вопросы, предназначенные _исключительно_ для выяснения мнения, задавать не рекомендуется. Это просто замечание; насколько я вижу, вы спрашиваете о стилистической корректности обсуждаемой метафоры, так что, кажется, все в порядке.

Comment: @Aer, вы правы: речь идет о стилистической корректеости.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Тянет сердце руки, тянет сердце руки любви, любви...**

Да, не всем всем нравится эта метафора, и не все критики одобряют творчество **широко известного и многими любимого поэта.** http://vspro.info/article/tysyacha-i-odin-stikh-mikhaila-gutserieva

Почему? Наверное,  она сложна для понимания, даже если разделить ее на части. Руки любви – необычное сочетание, также трудно представить, что у сердца есть руки.

Вот и не возникает яркого образа и эмоционального восприятия у тех читателей, которым ближе простой и доступный стих.

Comment: Понятно, что трудно представить. Но здесь олицетворение.

Comment: Олицетворение - особый вид метафоры. Метафора  - более общее понятие (определяется как перенос наименования с одной реалии на другую на основе сходства признаков).

Comment: >> "Почему? Наверное, она сложна для понимания, даже если разделить ее на части."


Да уж... Прямо Мандельштам или Бродский. Эстрадные "поэты" вообще сложны для понимания. Не для средних умов...

Comment: Поэзия прежде всего рассчитана на восприятие ее чувствами, а не умом, а к песенному тексту добавлены еще музыка, жесты, движения, цветовое оформление. Так создается единый образ, и поэт, вероятно,  учитывает эти особенности жанра. И вот интересно, если Вам нравится какой-нибудь поэт, Вы все его стихи считаете гениальными?

Comment: Прежде всего я стараюсь не разбрасываться словами типа "гениально"

Answer (score 2):

А мне нравится эта метафора.
Ведь если сердце преисполнено любовью, то и вправду хочется понаобнимать всё и вся вокруг.
Мне вспомнилось стихотворение Эдуарда Асадова, которого никак нельзя отнести к *эстрадным "поэтам"* (["Дорожите счастьем, дорожите"](http://www.stihi-rus.ru/1/Asadov/35.htm)).

*А для очень, очень добрых глаз

Нет ни склок, ни зависти, ни муки.

**Радость к вам сама протянет руки,**

Если сердце светлое у вас.*
. . .
*И поют дороги и мосты,

Краски леса и ветра событий,

Звезды, птицы, реки и цветы:

Дорожите счастьем, дорожите!*

И никакой "известный музыкальный критик" (**кому** известный?) не убедит меня в том, что у радости не может быть рук и что мосты, ветра и звезды не умеют петь!